# Why I can't send_keys to Twitch search bar in Python with Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to write a Selenium bot to search in twitch.
I can click the search bar but I can't send any value to the search bar.

what is the issue? I worked for hours but can't fix my problem.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class Twitch: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    def openTwitch(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.twitch.tv/")
        self.browser.maximize_window()

        try:
            barClick = WebDriverWait(self.browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/nav/div/div[2]/div/div')))
            barClick.click()
        except:
            print("Element not clickable")

        try:
            searchBar = WebDriverWait(self.browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tw-2a283106145a4249e75c7a6787c01324"]')))
            searchBar.send_keys("Xantares")  #this area is not working..
            searchBar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        except:
            print("Element not writable")

twtch = Twitch()
twtch.openTwitch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not take random generated ids, they are volatile so in the next run you will not reach the element.

For example you could take a reference from `input` tag like:

`searchBar = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'(//input[@type="search"])[1]')))`

There is a powerfool tool in the browser that can help you to find the right selector:

[image: Browser Console]

You should press `F12`, then in the `Elements` tab, press `CTRL + F`, it allows you to test the XPATH expressions there.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try insert the text inside `input` tag.

Something is wrong with your locator,
change with:

```
searchBar = WebDriverWait(self.browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="tw-relative"]//input[not(contains(@id, "hidden"))]')))
```

Comment: yeap something was wrong thanks for your answer ı fixed my issue.

Comment: @Canİlgu glad it worked, btw, you're wrong because the `id` has a dynamic value. If you look now, you can see that the id has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this ID(tw-2a283106145a4249e75c7a6787c01324) is valid? It looks like it's some randomly generated id.
If you would like to do it hardway, set focus to it, and use Actions to send keys.

Comment: Yes this ID is valid.You can see, when you right click to search bar then click inspect.. and this way is not hard way actually.